# ASP.NET Identity Linq query to fetch all users with claims for search word

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using Identity from ASP.NET Core to manage my users.
Now I want to search trough all the users and claims.

I can't figure out how to write the correct query in Linq to fetch the user with all his claims. What I now have is that whenever a claim value is matched a result is added in the list. So when I have firstName and lastName claim I end up with 2 results in the list. Also when only one claim matches I don't get all the other claims.

How can I retrieve the user info and all the matching claims whenever something hits the searchWords?

```
        var users = (from user in dbContext.Users
            join claims in dbContext.UserClaims
                on user.Id equals claims.UserId
            where searchWords.Contains(claims.ClaimValue)
            select new
            {
                ID = user.Id,
                Username = user.UserName,
                ClaimType = claims.ClaimType,
                ClaimValue = claims.ClaimValue
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: I am more familiar with this syntax, but maybe it's still helpful to you.
dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Claims.Any(c =>searchWords.Contains(c.ClaimValue)))
.Include(u => u.Claims)

Comment: The user doesn't have a claims relationship in dotnet identity

Comment: I do not understand which users you have to fetch? 1) Any with matched claim and its all claims 2) All users and get only matched claims 3) All user which have matched claim and only matched claims. Which DTO do  you expect?